# Flask App Simulating blocking API to abstract from web hook based callback

Tags: python-3.x, angular, multithreading, rest, flask

[image: REST API need]

I have Angular 8 web app. It needs to send some data for analysis to python flask App. This flask App will send it to 3rd party service and get response through webhook. 
My need is to provide a clean interface to the client so that there is no need to provide webhook from client. 
Hence I am trying to initiate a request from Flask app, wait until I get data from webhook and then return.
Here is the code.

```
#In autoscaled micro-service this will not work. Right now, the scaling is manual and set to 1 instance
#Hence keeping this sliding window list in RAM is okay.

 reqSlidingWindow =[]

@app.route('/handlerequest',methods = ['POST']) 
def Process_client_request_and_respond(param1,param2,param3):
    #payload code removed
    #CORS header part removed
    querystring={APIKey, 'https://mysvc.mycloud.com/postthirdpartyresponsehook'}
    response = requests.post(thirdpartyurl, json=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    if(response.status_code == SUCCESS):
        respdata = response.json()
        requestId = respdata["request_id"]
        requestobject = {}
        requestobject['requestId'] = requestId
        reqSlidingWindow.append(requestobject)

        #Now wait for the response to arrive through webhook
        #Keep checking the list if reqRecord["AllAnalysisDoneFlag"] is set to True. 
        #If set, read reqRecord["AnalysisResult"] = jsondata
        jsondata = None 
        while jsondata is None:
            time.sleep(2)
            for reqRecord in reqSlidingWindow:
                if(reqRecord["requestId"] == da_analysis_req_Id ):
                    print("Found matching req id in req list. Checking if analysis is done.")
                    print(reqRecord)
                   if(reqRecord["AllAnalysisDoneFlag"] == True):
                        jsondata = reqRecord["AnalysisResult"]
                        return jsonify({"AnalysisResult": "Success", "AnalysisData":jsondata})

@app.route('/webhookforresponse',methods = ['POST']) 
def process_thirdparty_svc_response(reqIdinResp):
print(request.data)  
print("response receieved at")
data = request.data.decode('utf-8')
jsondata = json.loads(data)
#
for reqRecord in reqSlidingWindow:
    #print("In loop. current analysis type" + reqRecord["AnalysisType"] )
    if(reqRecord["requestId"] == reqIdinResp ):
        reqRecord["AllAnalysisDoneFlag"] = True
        reqRecord["AnalysisResult"] = jsondata    
        return
```

I'm trying to maintain sliding window of requests in list. Upon the 
Observations so far:

1. First, this does not work. The function of 'webhookforresponse' does not seem to run until my request function comes out. i.e. my while() loop appears to block everything though I have a time.sleep(). My assumption is that flask framework would ensure that callback is called since sleep in another 'route' gives it adequate time and internally flask would be multithreaded?
2. I tried running python threads for the sliding window data structure and also used RLocks. This does not alter behavior. I have not tried flask specific  threading.

**Questions:**

1. What is the right architecture of the above need with flask? I need clean REST interface without callback for angular client. Everything else can change.
2. If the above code to be used, what changes should I make? Is threading required at all? 
   Though I can use database and then pick from there, it still requires polling the sliding window.
3. Should I use multithreading specific to flask? Is there any specific example with skeletal design, threading library choices?
   Please suggest the right way to proceed to achieve abstract REST API for angular client which hides the back end callbacks and other complexities.

Comment: Flasks development server only has one process and one thread.  That means it can only handle one request at a time.  If the request sleeps, it still would not allow another request until the sleeping one finished.  You can try running a WSGI server locally to see if you get the desired results.

Comment: I tried with gunicorn on Google App Engine. Results have same behavior. For now, I have gone for standard REST implementation i.e. without waiting for result, I return the ID to client. Then after fixed wait time at client, I created another read request to read the result. But this is hardcoded wait, not a proper asynchronous read.

Comment: If you are looking for async behaviour you will need async tools.  Consider looking into using Gevent to make flask async without much modification to your code.  If you are using Gevent, you need to use gevents sleep to trigger task switching ( http://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.html#sleeping ).  If it is a long wait for an http call, consider using celery and emailing the client when the work is complete.  If neither of those work consider using an asynchronous web framework that is Flask-like such as Starlette.

Comment: Thanks. Probably this will solve my problem. I will use it.